# is it best expressional condition?

Tags: javascript

I am working to get a final value from a function, i have two clickable buttons, one is previous and another is next. for clicking both, i am getting the slide show count. to get this result i am using the following codes. it works better, but till i beleave that, there may be a single line solution for this..

can any one correct this code to minimize ?

```
var tdLength = 7;
    var num = 0;
    $('a.buttons').click(function(){
        num = ($(this).attr('id') == "next-arrow") ? num +=1 : num -=1;
        num = ( num > tdLength) ? 1 : num;
        num = (num < 1) ? tdLength : num;
        alert(num);
    })
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My shot:

```
var num = 0;
function add(amount) {
    num = (num + tdLength - 1 + amount) % tdLength + 1
    alert(num);
}

$('#next-arrow').click(function(){add(1)});
$('#prev-arrow').click(function(){add(-1)});
```

The wicked:

```
num = (num + tdLength - 1 + amount) % tdLength + 1
```

Always yields a value in `[1..tdLength]` (inclusive) for reasonable `amount` values. Inpsired by @Jon answer.

Comment: I am getting the values by increasing and decreasing the values by `1`. in case if i require the values by `2` or `3` how to handle? ex: 2,4,6,8 or 3,6,9 like so?

Answer (score 2):

One idea is that you can replace this

```
num = (num > tdLength) ? 1 : num;
num = (num < 1) ? tdLength : num;
```

with the line below, which is also guaranteed to provide a result in the interval `[0 .. (tdLength-1)]`:

```
num = (num + tdLength) % tdLength;
```

The difference here is that your code uses a 1-based index while % results in 0-based indexes.

You can also shorten the first line:

```
num = ($(this).attr('id') == "next-arrow") ? num +=1 : num -=1;
```

Since you 're in control, add a `data-skip` (or similar) attribute to your links (e.g. `<a id="prev-arrow" data-skip="-1">...</a>`), which will allow you to do this instead:

```
num += parseInt($(this).data('skip'));
```

So all this together gives:

```
var tdLength = 7;
var num = 0; // "first" is preselected
$('a.buttons').click(function(){
    num = (num + parseInt($(this).data('skip')) + tdLength) % tdLength;
    alert(num);
})
```

Comment: `num += $(this).data('skip');` going to do string concatenation